# How does Craft handle uploading assets to AWS?

Tags: upload, aws, amazon

When users upload assets to a Craft CMS site setup to use AWS, do the assets go directly to AWS or are they uploaded to the Craft server first?

The reason I ask is I'm building an area where users upload potentially large files from the frontend, and it's quite likely a lot of users will choose to do it at the same time.

If the files are uploaded to the Craft server first, I might have to spec-up the server a bit more and would welcome any tips for helping Craft handle the multiple large uploads as efficiently as possible.

If the files are simply uploaded to AWS, I take it that means there will be little impact on the Craft server and I won't need to worry about any of this. Is that right?

Comment: They are uploaded to Craft first to a temporary file, then Assets uses the Asset Source to work out where to send them next - either the local file system or a remote one. For handling large uploads in general you could look at this plugin: https://superbig.co/plugins/large-upload

Comment: Hi Josh. That's a bummer. I've signed up to be notified when that plugin is ready. I guess if a large file is sent to both the Craft server and then from there to Amazon AWS, that's a double whammy. Ouch.

Comment: Yep, but I think it has to be so that Craft can log all the file meta (height, width, file size, file kind etc) as well as index it for searching etc.

Comment: @JoshAngell you should add that as an answer. :)

Comment: @BradBell done! It could definitely be improved upon ...

Comment: @JoshAngell honestly, meta data is just part of the equation. While technically feasible (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html), there are a bunch of caveats - AWS Asset Source specific, exposing credentials that allow upload to a bucket and an upload flow that is disconnected from the general Assets upload flow. If you wanted, though, you probably might be hack together a plugin that allows uploading straight to AWS and then indexes the file back in, but I'd save that for Craft 3, what with the optimized indexing and all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are uploaded to Craft first to a temporary file, then Assets uses the Asset Source to work out where to send them next - either the local file system or a remote one.

For handling large uploads in general you could look at this plugin: https://superbig.co/plugins/large-upload

Answer (score 1):

A simple but inelegant workaround for very large files is to upload them directly to the AWS bucket and then update the Asset Index in the Craft CP